# Как убрать кавычки?

Tags: php

Как тут можно убрать кавычки?

```
Игра: #n101 | #n3224
#h11:#m58 #T_11_58
Игрок 1: "Пара"(Q♦️ Q♠️)
Игрок 2: "Две пары"(A♥️ A♠️ Q♦️ Q♠️)
Результат: "#П2 Две пары!"
```

Вот тут: **Результат: "#П2 Две пары!"**

Код:

```
$Combination = $GameData['Value']['SC']['S'][3]['Value'];
$CombReplace = str_replace('Победил игрок 2 c комбинацией', '#П2', $Combination);
$CombReplace = str_replace('Победил игрок 1 c комбинацией', '#П1', $CombReplace);
$CombReplace = str_replace('Победили оба игрока c комбинацией', '#Ничья', $CombReplace);
```

Вот откуда идет вся информация по играм:

```
 $LiveGames  = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://1x-bet86595.com/LiveFeed/Get1x2_Zip?sports=236&count=10&mode=3"),true);
    $LiveGames  = $LiveGames ['Value'];

    for ($i = 0; $i<count($LiveGames ); $i++) {
        $GameData = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://1x-bet86595.com/LiveFeed/GetGameZip?id=" . $LiveGames[$i]['I'] . ""), true);
```

Вот как я вывожу

```
"Игрок 1: $Comb1Replace({$Cards1Combination})"
```

Мне нужно, чтобы просто выводилось **Результат: #П2 Две пары**

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: мб вы начнете с того, чтобы привести код, который эту строку выводит?

Comment: Добавил код, который выводит эту строку

Comment: а разве нужно выводить не так `"Игрок 1: " $Comb1Replace({$Cards1Combination})` или `"Игрок 1: . $Comb1Replace({$Cards1Combination}) . "`?

Comment: `$CombReplace = str_replace('"', '', $CombReplace);`

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло. Можете еще подсказать как добавить #П2 Две пары в один хештег? Должно получить #П2_Две_Пары, я перепробовал много разных способов, но так и не смог найти решение. Может вы сможете помочь?